# How to select item / child / object in treelistview via textChanged-Event?

Tags: .net, select, treeview, searchbar, treelistview

I am using treelistview from brightideassoftware and want to select a specific child in my treelist.

The type of my object is 'MeasurementFile'.

```
public class MeasurementFile
{ 
    private string fileName = string.Empty;
    private List<SignalObjects> signals = new List<SignalObjects>();
    ...
}
```

The type of the children is 'SelectObjects':

```
public class SignalObjects
    {
        private string signalName = string.Empty;
        public SignalObjects(string signalName)
        {
            this.signalName = signalName;
        }

        public string SignalName { get { return signalName; } }      
}
```

So each MeasurementFile does have a list of signals.

My treelistview looks like:

```
MyWinForm:

name/signal                //Column

-myFile1
|_____signal1
|_____signal2
|_____signal3
-myFile2
-myFile3
-myFile4
```

Now i want so search after a specific child. If the MeasurementFileobject is expanded and i enter something in my searchTextEdit, all matched children should be selected. If i enter "al1" in my searchbar, the child with the name "signal1" should be selected.

My question is: How can i select the matched children?

I tried ...

```
 private void searchSignalTextEdit_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                
            string text = searchSignalTextEdit.Text;                
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                foreach (MeasurementFile measurementFile in treeListView1.Objects)
                {
                    if (treeListView1.IsExpanded(measurementFile))
                    {    
                        foreach (SignalObjects signal in measurementFile.getSignals)
                        {
                            if (signal.SignalName.Contains(text))
                            {
                                treeListView1.SelectObject(signal);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

... but nothing was been selected. I would be glad if anybody can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use linq and regular expressions
something like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(...);

var signals = MeasurementFile.Signals.Select(x=>x.signalName).Asenumebrable;

var matchingsignals = signals.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x)).ToList();

var matching = MeasurementFile.Signals.Where(d => matchingsignals.Contains(d.signalName));
```